# MPI - кластер на машинах с Windows 7

Tags: windows, hpc, распараллеливание, mpi

Здравствуйте! В рамках курсовой работы занимаюсь разработкой вычислительного кластера на базе компьютерного класса с машинами на Windows 7.

Выбор пал на MPI, а конкретно на MPICH.

[Здесь](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/) скачал [неофициальную сборку](http://www.mpich.org/static/tarballs/1.4.1p1/mpich2-1.4.1p1-win-ia32.msi) под Windows.
Воспользовался [этой](http://iproc.ru/programming/mpich-windows/) инструкцией. 
Для теста поставил на Vmware две виртуальные машины с Windows 7 (BIGBROTHER и LITTLESISTER).
Все хорошо работало только на одном host, когда же я пытался запустить `mpiexec.exe` на двух машинах, то выпадала [ошибка](http://pastebin.com/JimcBW2N).

[Здесь](http://lists.mpich.org/pipermail/discuss/2013-December/) пытался найти помощь, но мне сказали, что `mpich` больше не поддерживает Windows. Предложили воспользоваться [MSMPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx). 
[Скачал](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39961), установил, настроил.
`MPI Hello World` нормально отработала (BIGBROTHER и LITTLESISTER обозначили себя через `printf`). Однако, когда я попытался реализовать простую перессылку сообщений (`MPI_Send` и `MPI_Recv`), опять ошибка:

```
job aborted:
[ranks] message
[0] terminated
[1] fatal error
Fatal error in PMPI_Recv: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
MPI_Recv(buf=0x0042FBDC, count=64, MPI_CHAR, src=0, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x0042FB78) failed
[ch3:sock] received packet of unknown type (1234)
```

Код программы по пересылке сообщений: http://www.sourcepod.com/psznnl57-21098

Вопросы:

1. Может быть я зря отказался от http://www.mpich.org/static/tarballs/1.4.1p1/mpich2-1.4.1p1-win-ia32.msi ? Не знаю, поддерживается ли она официально еще.
2. Может быть я зря выбрал MSMPI? Гугление ни к чему толковому не привело, очень часто появлялись ссылки на серверные Windows. На конференции MPICH сказали, что PVM использовать нет смысла. А что тогда имеет? Вторая распространенная библиотека и опять ошибка.

Спасибо за Ваше внимание.

Comment: Найдите Live-CD типа PelicanHPC и используйте MPI на Linux, а не на позапрошлостарой прошивке для консолей.